# Upgrade in Pre Populated Database Android

Tags: android, database

I am using prepopulated database in my app but when I add new rows in prepopulated database and increase the version of DB it doesn't copy the new content. To copy new content I have to reinstall the app.

Please help me to resolve this problem I want to copy new rows when database is upgraded.

Here is my DBHelper.java

```
package com.suvariyaraj.algorithms.Database;

/**
 * Created by GOODBOY-PC on 04/06/16.
 */
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ExternalDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Path to the device folder with databases
    public static String DB_PATH;

    //Database file name
    public static String DB_NAME;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    public final Context context;
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
        return database;
    }

    public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
        super(context, databaseName, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
        //Write a full path to the databases of your application
        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
        DB_NAME = databaseName;
        openDataBase();
        Log.d("mycheck", "constructor "+database.getVersion());
    }

    //This piece of code will create a database if it’s not yet created
    public void createDataBase() {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
                throw new Error("Error copying database!");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
        }
    }

    //Performing a database existence check
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
        try {
            String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while ch1ecking db");
        }
        //Android doesn’t like resource leaks, everything should
        // be closed
        if (checkDb != null) {
            checkDb.close();
        }
        return checkDb != null;
    }

    //Method for copying the database
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        //Open a stream for reading from our ready-made database
        //The stream source is located in the assets
        InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        //Path to the created empty database on your Android device
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Now create a stream for writing the database byte by byte
        OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //Copying the database
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        //Don’t forget to close the streams
        localDbStream.close();
        externalDbStream.close();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        if (database == null) {
            createDataBase();
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
        return database;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (database != null) {
            database.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d("mycheck", "on create");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Upgrade",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("mycheck", "Upgrade");
        context.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
        openDataBase();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't add the changes in your onUpgrade method. That method is for you to modify/update your existing databases. If you don't do anything here, then the only way the changes is reflected is for the user to reinstall the app.

onUpgrade:

> Called when the database needs to be upgraded. The implementation should use this method to drop tables, add tables, or do anything else it needs to upgrade to the new schema version.

So for example:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
if (oldVersion < YOUR_NEW_DB_VERSION) {
     db.execSQL(YOUR_QUERY_TO_ADD_NEW_DATA_TO_EXISTING_TABLE);
}
}
```

Also check out this [post](https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/how-android-sqlite-onupgrade) if you need more help with using onUpgrade. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add this snippet of code but I tried this it didn't work. Can you please give me exact code for onUpgrade?

Comment: I don't know what data/rows you are trying to add to which table in your database. If you are having trouble with writing the query to insert new rows into existing database, just follow the format from this post http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-insert/ and once you have your query, just replace it in the example I provided you in my post